# WCF hosted with IIS performance Tuning

Tags: performance, wcf, iis, load

I am working for a large corporation.

We have set up a IIS 6.0 WCF web service.

We are currently hitting 10 000 requests an hour.

Some of these requests are not being processed.

Are there any ways on improving the performance of the IIS 6.0 server or WCF 4.0?

Any ideas is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Guess i should break the questions into IIS 6.0 questions and WCF 4.0 questions

Comment: Things is surely there are standards in how to performance tune an iis 6.0 wcf 4.0 application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. updated the wcf web.config in connectionManagement set maxconnection to 100
2. added this to web config serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10000" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="10000"

Seems to have increased the performance.